# Azure FileShare Directory Length via REST with SAS Key

Tags: azure

I am trying to get the length of a directory on Azure FileShare using Rest api with SAS key authentication.

Right now I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files
to get the list of files and then obtaining the length of list.

Azure has put an upper limit of 5000 entities on the rest api. Need to get the actual number of files in the directory without limit.

Limited to use only SAS key authentication and only on Linux OS machines.

With above constraints, I would like to obtain the actual number of files in a directory within a FileShare on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

The REST request is returning a marker object in response. The value of this marker can be used to get the next elements in the list by adding to the url parameters in the next request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-directories-and-files